# React native app button click does not work in expo for my project

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, button, expo

I'm using expo to test my react native application and when testing with an IPhone, none of the buttons are responsive. It's completely successful with android, and other features work with the Iphone. I have a scanner that was able to read data. How do you trouble shoot this issue and will this continue to be an issue if I deploy this to production?

Here's my App.js file.

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import BarcodeScannerScreen  from './BarcodeScanner.js';
import ProfileScreen from "./views/ProfileScreen"
import BathroomSelectionScreen from "./views/InClubScreens/BathroomSelectionScreen.js"
import ClubDetails from "./views/ClubSelectionScreens/ClubDetails.js"
import ClubMain from "./views/ClubSelectionScreens/ClubMain.js"
import BarSelection from './views/DrinkSelectionScreens/BarSelection.js'
import DrinkMenu from './views/DrinkSelectionScreens/DrinkMenu.js'
import DrinkSelection from './views/DrinkSelectionScreens/DrinkSelection.js' 
import BathroomList from "./views/InClubScreens/BathroomList.js"
import Checkout from './views/DrinkSelectionScreens/Checkout.js'
import { MyProvider } from './store/context';
import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <StripeProvider
      publishableKey="pk_test_51LlDznHYav5iWqq6j2SnnvtwAZXvha9jZERJeilcJeRtpFoZ6eu21ZjiTGun7vvstGLaWsL4FwpsoQ1X25MXxM4W00dzk1zCx9"
      //urlScheme="your-url-scheme" // required for 3D Secure and bank redirects
      //merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.{{YOUR_APP_NAME}}" // required for Apple Pay
    >
    <MyProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Scanner">
        <Stack.Screen name="Scanner"  options= {{headerShown:false}} component={BarcodeScannerScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#4F47C7',
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }} headerStyle name="Profile Creation" component={ProfileScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Bathroom Selection" component={BathroomSelectionScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Club Details" component={ClubDetails} options={{
          title: '',
        }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Club Main" component={ClubMain}  options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })} />  
        <Stack.Screen name="Bar Selection" component={BarSelection} />   
        <Stack.Screen name="Drink Menu" component={DrinkMenu} />  
        <Stack.Screen name="Checkout" component={Checkout} />  
        <Stack.Screen name="Drink Selection" component={DrinkSelection} 
        options= {{headerShown:false}}/>    
        <Stack.Screen name="Bathroom List" component={BathroomList} /> 
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </MyProvider>
    </StripeProvider>
  </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
  }
})
```

here's the code of the landing screen. The scanner function works, and navigates but the onPress doesn't work in Iphone. works successfully in android

```
// screens/HomeScreen.js

import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MyContext,MyProvider } from './store/context';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import service from './api/customer'
import { Alert } from "react-native";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const {state, clear,load} = useContext(MyContext);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [inputCode, setInputCode] = useState('');
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    console.log(data)
    service.getVenueInfo(data)
    // You can perform additional checks on the barcode data if needed
    .then(jsonData => {
      console.log(jsonData)
      if(jsonData.data.venue){ //jsonData.action.payload.data.venue
        load(jsonData)
        navigation.navigate('Club Main', { name: state.venue.venue_name })
      }
      else{
        setScanned(false);
      }
      
    })
    .catch(error => {console.log(error)
        setScanned(false);
    });
    //navigation.navigate('Club Main', { barcodeData: data });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (text) => {
    setInputCode(text);
  };

  const handleTextInputSubmit = () => {
    // You can perform additional checks on the input code if needed
    navigation.navigate('Result', { barcodeData: inputCode });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.topLeft]} />
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.topRight]} />
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.bottomLeft]} />
        <View style={[styles.corner, styles.bottomRight]} />
      </View>
       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.actionButton} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
       <Ionicons name="document-text" onPress={()=>{Alert.alert('Ive been pressed')}}  size={32} color="white" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  actionButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 40, // Adjust this value to set the distance from the bottom
    right: 40, // Adjust this value to set the distance from the right
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30, // Half of the width and height to make it circular
    backgroundColor: '#4F47C7', // Your desired background color
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5, // Add elevation for a slight shadow effect (Android)
    shadowColor: '#000', // Shadow color (iOS)
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 }, // Shadow offset (iOS)
    shadowOpacity: 0.8, // Shadow opacity (iOS)
    shadowRadius: 3, // Shadow radius (iOS)
  },
  scanner: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 8,
  },
  overlay: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  box: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent:'center',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.3,
    top: (Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.6 - Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.081) / 2,
    left: (Dimensions.get('window').width - Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6) / 2,
  },
  corner: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    borderWidth: 6,
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  topLeft: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  topRight: {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  bottomLeft: {
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
  },
  bottomRight: {
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
  }
});
```

I can add config files also if that will help

Comment: add your code, how we know what is the failure, we don't even can see your code

Comment: Just added code

Answer (score 0):

which onPress that doesn't work?
I saw you have 2 action onPress, both is working.. on the testing snack

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.actionButton} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
    <Ionicons name="document-text" onPress={()=>{Alert.alert('Ive been pressed')}}  size={32} color="white" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Snack link
https://snack.expo.dev/@rudiahmad/testing

Comment: All of the onPresses are unresponsive. Its when I run this on expo that I get unresponsive buttons. snack is fine. and android is fine